# Bidirectional Converter Switching problem on Mosfet

Tags: mosfet, pwm, dc-dc-converter, switching, bidirectional

I want to ask. I designed a bidirectional converter with synchronous buck converter as the circuit configuration.
The problem is, the switching mosfet. When i applied lower voltage at the input (10V), i can produce 5V output. The signal also came smooth. But when i increase the input voltage, i can see clearly that it started to oscillate (when i'm trying to increase it to 14V, i can produce 7V output but the oscillate came out).
Here're the signal at both of the mosfet. Yellow signal represents high side of the mosfet and blue signal represents low side of the mosfet.
Oh yeah, and i used P75NF75 as the mosfet. And TLP250 as the gate driver with 10V VCC.
[image: Switching signal between high side mosfet and low side mosfet]

[image: Switching signal between high side mosfet and low side mosfet]

Schematic from [related question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/262562/conventional-bidirectional-dc-dc-converter-calculation?rq=1)

[image]

Thank you so much !

Comment: Please show us the circuit diagram. Just making sure, the problem is to do with the spike from the drain source of the MOSFET right?

Comment: I want to added the circuit diagram, but i'm a newbie here, so only can attach 2 files at one post T___T. Yeah Sir, the problem with the spike is from the drain-source of both of the mosfet. And also i didn't use a snubber circuit yet.

The circuit diagram is the same as in this post : http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/262562/conventional-bidirectional-dc-dc-converter-calculation?rq=1

Comment: I used this kind of circuit Sir as my gate driver @Bradman175 : http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-xtPqknAPDbU/UYAQuZkW2mI/AAAAAAAAAlY/TkZJ6XUsZ40/s1600/4.png

With the V supply = 10V. And Vmos as the main DC line (in my case, the problem is when Vmos is 14V, so the output is 7V)

Comment: Ok with the image diagram in the question you just added, you could try adding resistors before each gate to slow down turn on and turn off.

Comment: And with the circuit in the link you just commented, the load should be on the positive side of the battery.

Comment: @Bradman175 Oh, i used that circuit for the high side of the mosfet. And for the low side of the mosfet, i used this kind of circuit : http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-3SFfF3wVyPw/UYAOpJv2aDI/AAAAAAAAAk8/5rMX_nM06iE/s1600/1.png

And about try adding resistor before each gate, in the gate driver circuit i used, there're a voltage divider between the gate. Did you refer to that resistor ?
Thank you so much for your reply

Comment: Actually kinda did refer to that resistor... try putting another one of larger value but on the other side of the 1k so it's right before the MOSFET gate.

Comment: @Bradman175 My first question is, why does it need to be slowed sir ?
And my PWM signal looked like this sir ( represents as a blue signal. Just don't mind the yellow signal) http://i339.photobucket.com/albums/n468/lolalabs123/20170104_134900.jpg
And Did you mean by this Sir : http://i339.photobucket.com/albums/n468/lolalabs123/4.jpg

Thank you

Comment: That's where I proposed to put a resistor but if it still doesn't work, then I guess I'll have to leave you with someone else.

Comment: @Bradman175 Oh, it's okay Sir. Really big thanks to you. It doesn't matter if it's work or not, but at least i tried. ahahaha.. Btw, what resistor value should i put on the gate of the mosfet ? Thank you so much for your reply and your kindness !

Comment: @Bradman175 Hang on, he didn't try it yet.

Comment: @Braham You could try 100 \$\Omega\$. Or maybe it's better to start with 10 \$\Omega\$, increase the voltage and see if it still goes ringing. Why is your \$B_1\$ not grounded?